# unable to parse json into csv using jq

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I have a JSON file that I want to convert into a CSV file using the jq in a shell script. I want to create a single row from this entire JSON file. I have to extract value from values. The row output should be something like

null,642,642,412,0,null,null

`Here is my JSON file`

```
{
     "data": [
   {
     "name": "exits",
     "period": "lifetime",
     "values": [
       {
         "value": {}
       }
     ],
     "title": "Exits",
     "description": "Number of times someone exited the carousel"
   },
   {
     "name": "impressions",
     "period": "lifetime",
     "values": [
       {
         "value": 642
       }
     ],
     "title": "Impressions",
     "description": "Total number of times the media object has been seen"
   },
   {
     "name": "reach",
     "period": "lifetime",
     "values": [
       {
         "value": 412
       }
     ],
     "title": "Reach",
     "description": "Total number of unique accounts that have seen the media object"
   },
   {
     "name": "replies",
     "period": "lifetime",
     "values": [
       {
         "value": 0
       }
     ],
     "title": "Replies",
     "description": "Total number of replies to the carousel"
   },
   {
     "name": "taps_forward",
     "period": "lifetime",
     "values": [
       {
         "value": {}
       }
     ],
     "title": "Taps Forward",
     "description": "Total number of taps to see this story's next photo or video"
   },
   {
     "name": "taps_back",
     "period": "lifetime",
     "values": [
       {
         "value": {}
       }
     ],
     "title": "Taps Back",
     "description": "Total number of taps to see this story's previous photo or video"
   }
 ]
}
```

Hi tried using this jq command : 
`.data | map(.values[].value) | @csv`

This is giving the following output: 
jq: error (at :70): object ({}) is not valid in a csv row
exit status 5

So when I am getting this empty JSON object it is reflecting an error.

Please Help!!

The row output should be something like

null,642,642,412,0,null,null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `length==0` here is dubious at best. To check for {} one could write:

```
jq '.data | map(.values[].value | if . == {} then "null" else . end) | @csv'
```

Similarly for [].

Answer (score 2):

If you run the command without the @csv part you will see that the output is:

```
[
  {},
  642,
  412,
  0,
  {},
  {}
]
```

By replacing the empty objects with "null": (length == 0)

```
jq '.data | map(.values[].value) | map(if (type == "object" and length == 0 ) then "null" else . end) | @csv'

Output:
"\"null\",642,412,0,\"null\",\"null\""
```

Per suggestion from @aaron (see comment). The following can produce the requested output without extra post-processing. Disclaimer: this is not working with my jq 1.5, but working on jqplay with jq 1.6.

```
jq --raw-output '.data | map(.values[].value) | map(if (type == "object" and length == 0 ) then "null" else . end) | join(",")'

Output:
null,642,412,0,null,null
```

Comment: To handle the quotes I suggest using `| join(",")` and `-r`/`--raw-output` instead of the `csv` filter : https://jqplay.org/s/3Z9coUQlTz ; that said, having quotes around the string values would work just fine in the context of CSV, where the fields can be quoted in case they may contain an occurence of the field separator

Comment: @Aaron can you put the full command. I've tried append '@join...' as you suggested, and I'm getting string (",") and number (642) cannot be added

Comment: `jq --raw-output '.data | map(.values[].value) | map(if (length == 0 ) then "null" else . end) | join(",")'`, if you checked the jqplay link it provides the full command on the bottom :)

Comment: @Aaron I will embed into my answer, TY

Comment: Thanks, guys. It helped. would it be possible to print 0 where ever the result was 0 and null where ever the json object is blank?

Comment: Note that `0|length == 0` and `"" | length == 0` so using `length` to check for {} is inappropriate or incorrect.